# Programmatically reading a user's LinkedIn User Profile with user's permission

Tags: linkedin-api

Is there a way to read a user's LinkedIn User Profile with user's permission. We have a community portal and our users update their profile to be found by other community members. To simplify the process of user profile population, we want to fetch users LinkedIn profiles (with their explicit permission) and store it in our portal, instead of them effectively entering more or less the same info on our portal. Grateful for any advice, pointers, tips etc.

Many thanks,
Oz

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Register for a developer account with LinkedIn to access their API and use that to query data https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/integrations/people/profile-api?context=linkedin/consumer/context

Comment: Thanks for this pointer nopassport1. We did this but we are not getting the About info from LinkedIn. Actually, we are not even getting the "localizedHeadline" value. Our app has been verified but it only has "r_liteprofile" permissions. And we are not able to edit the Permissions settings of the app. Is there any way to get the About text from LinkedIn. Thanks.

Comment: I guess your next best option would be to try and use something like Puppeteer: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer or Nightmare.js: https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare to scrape the details of a given list of people. Both libraries are dead easy to use and there are ample resources online for both should you get stuck